# Proof feedback $ f $ is differentiable at $c$ it is also continous at $c$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Hi I have done my own proof of this theorem, and it's likely wrong as it's different to the proof in the book which is also very simple.
I would love some feedback in what wrong assumptions I am making. I think it may be that I'm bounding x-c. Or maybe I can not use the absolute value?

Here it goes:
$ f $ is differentiable at $ c $ so we can say
$$ f'(c) = \lim_{ x \to c } \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}$$

I thought I may be able to say that: $$ |x-c| < \delta $$
so in absolute terms and assuming x-c is smaller than 1.
$$ f'(c) > \lim_{ x \to c } \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{\delta}$$
then:
$$ f'(c)\delta > \lim_{ x \to c } f(x) - f(c)$$
Where I thought I can say that $f'(c)\delta = \epsilon $
Or is the problem here as $f'(c) = 0 $ is a possibility?

If this is wrong, can I make it work by adding something?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful with the sign of $f(x) - f(c)$ when writing your second inequality, and before all with handling limits. You cannot write right away an inequality involving a limit: in your case, you have to write the equality for a given $x$ and then make $x$ goes to $c$. As a result, you will not end up with a strict equality even if you have a strict equality for any $x$. (Think of letting $x$ goes to zero in $x > 0$ for example)

Here is how I would do:

$\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}$ converges as $x$ tends to $c$ so this quantity is bounded in a neighborhood of $c$, i.e. there exists $M > 0$ and $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \neq c$ in $]c-\delta, c+\delta[$, $\left|\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}\right| \leq M$. Therefore,for all such $x$ we have

$$
|f(x) - f(c)| \leq M |x-c|
$$

and thus $f(x)$ converges to $f(c)$ as $x$ converges to $c$.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was more or less my original thought process. So this way would be ok? Also, the way you wrote it, that's called the Lipschitz Condition? 
I remember it looks quite similar to an exercise in the book (Understanding Analysis) I'm trying to work through.

Comment: No problem! Yes, the Lipschitz condition is $\exists M, \forall x,y, |f(x)-f)y)| \leq M|x-y|$, but notice that here $c$ is fixed, so this is not the Lipschitz condition.

Comment: thanks! I see now.